# Why Feature Envy sample code in the clean code book is a code smell?

Tags: coding-style

I am reading clean code and in the 17 section it is said that when a class is more interested in the fields and functions of another class it means that feature envy. then the following sample exist there:

```
public class HourlyPayCalculator {
public Money calculateWeeklyPay(HourlyEmployee e) {
int tenthRate = e.getTenthRate().getPennies();
int tenthsWorked = e.getTenthsWorked();
int straightTime = Math.min(400, tenthsWorked);
int overTime = Math.max(0, tenthsWorked - straightTime);
int straightPay = straightTime * tenthRate;
int overtimePay = (int)Math.round(overTime*tenthRate*1.5); 
return new Money(straightPay + overtimePay);
 }
}
```

How this sample is a feature envy?

Can anyone make this clear for me?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example *calculateWeeklyPay* is showing signs of feature envy because it's heavily reliant on the internals of the **HourlyEmployee** class. Instead of asking the **HourlyEmployee** for its fields and then calculating the pay outside of it, **HourlyEmployee** class can have a method like *calculatePay* that performs these calculations internally.

It can be refactored like this:

```java
public class HourlyEmployee {
    // ... Other methods and fields ...

    public Money calculateWeeklyPay() {
        int tenthRate = this.getTenthRate().getPennies();
        int tenthsWorked = this.getTenthsWorked();
        int straightTime = Math.min(400, tenthsWorked);
        int overTime = Math.max(0, tenthsWorked - straightTime);
        int straightPay = straightTime * tenthRate;
        int overtimePay = (int)Math.round(overTime * tenthRate * 1.5);
        
        return new Money(straightPay + overtimePay);
    }
}

// And then the HourlyPayCalculator would be simplified:
public class HourlyPayCalculator {
    public Money calculateWeeklyPay(HourlyEmployee e) {
        return e.calculateWeeklyPay();
    }
}
```